# Post Identity Server 4 Registration

Tags: identityserver4

I have identity server 4 setup and my asp net core app working with it. If you hit a secure endpoint it redirects to Identity Server and you can login. Once you login it then redirects back to the url you were originally trying to access. What I would like to do is check that you have registered in my database before you get redirected. I thought that I could change 'RedirectUris' to a url of my choice but when I do that it has no effect. A breakpoint on that end point is never hit. What do I need to do in order to setup a post identity server login registration screen?

Is this the right way of doing it?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: What do you mean by  `What I would like to do is check that you have registered in my database before you get redirected` if the user is not registered how the login is succeed?

Comment: If you want to use the registration process, then make sure in your register link you have added the RedirectUrl as Quersystring

Comment: @MJK They have registered with IdSr and exist in the IdSr database but when they return to my application I have no record of them existing. I need to create them.When in the process do I create a user in my database?

Comment: You can get the logged in user id and name in ClaimsPrincipal (user.Identiy). Definitely you will not stored the user details in your database

Comment: @MJK I have to store something in my database, the logged in user id? Otherwise how to I associate anything with that user?

Comment: Aha! you can store id or user name (preferable) for CreatedBy or UpdatedBy but your database do not need to know the user is registered or not, that is for IdServer

Comment: @MJK Should my api be doing this transparently when it receives an authenticated request or should each client have to 'register' a user with my api specifically? What's the norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to get the user details in your application.

IdentityToken contains user name if you include Name scope.
If it is a web application then you may find the name on `((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity)`

You can also add claims as you need, like userid, role etc

#### Comment

> should each client have to 'register' a user with my api specifically?
> What's the norm?

Depends on your requirements and what you are requesting for. On my case user must have allowed scope to access the api

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it better now. Any request to my api, if the user has the allowed scope, and I haven't seen that user before then I'll create them so I can associate records with them